# How to change the space between the section number and section in toc?

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]

I am writing a normal article, which the number of sections has gone over 100. The space between the 100th section and the number 100 is too small.

What could be adjusted to make it wider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package and its `\cftsecnumwidth` length, which holds the width used for `sec(tion)num(bers)`.

It's better to increase the current value it by some other value instead of direct usage of `\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{...}`. (The value of `20pt` applied here is a pure guess, however.)

Note: The explicit usage of `\setcounter` is just for demonstration of larger section numbers only.

The numbers are left aligned...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{20pt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{One}
\section{Two}
\section{Three}
\section{Four}

\setcounter{section}{100}

\section{One}
\section{Two}
\section{Three}
\section{Four}

\end{document}
```

[image]